# How to find out duplicate values in a row in Pyspark Data frame

Tags: pyspark

My data frame looks like -

```
val1     val2     val3
1         0         1
4         0         4
3         3         4
4         2         2
```

My final data frame should be -

```
val1     val2     val3  dup
1         0         1    1
4         0         4    4
3         3         4    3
4         2         2    2
```

Comment: What did you tried?

Answer (score 0):

creating dataframe

```
a = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("1", "0", "0","A"),
    ("1", "0", "2","B"),
    ("1", "1", "2","C"),
    ("1", "1", "3","H"),
    ("1", "2", "2","D"),
    ("1", "2", "2","E")
], ["val1", "val2", "val3","val4"])
```

create a list and explode and get counts.

```
df_a= a.withColumn('arr_val', array(col('val1'),col('val2'),col('val3')) )
df_b = df_a.withColumn('repeats', explode(col('arr_val')) ).\
     groupby(['val1','val2','val3','repeats']).count().\
     filter(col('count')>1)

df_a
+----+----+----+----+---------+
|val1|val2|val3|val4|arr_val  |
+----+----+----+----+---------+
|1   |0   |0   |A   |[1, 0, 0]|
|1   |0   |2   |B   |[1, 0, 2]|
|1   |1   |2   |C   |[1, 1, 2]|
|1   |1   |3   |H   |[1, 1, 3]|
|1   |2   |2   |D   |[1, 2, 2]|
|1   |2   |2   |E   |[1, 2, 2]|
+----+----+----+----+---------+

df_b
+----+----+----+-------+-----+
|val1|val2|val3|repeats|count|
+----+----+----+-------+-----+
|   1|   0|   0|      0|    2|
|   1|   2|   2|      2|    2|
|   1|   1|   3|      1|    2|
|   1|   1|   2|      1|    2|
+----+----+----+-------+-----+
```

I do feel this unoptimized.

if some can optimize using
`expr('filter(arr_val, x-> Count(x)>1)')`